# Dokka plugin not found in Android studio 3

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-dokka

I'm trying to use the dokka plugin in my Kotlin project, but I'm getting the following message:

> Error:(7, 0) Plugin with id 'org.jetbrains.dokka' not found.

I'm using Android Studio version 3.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you added dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:${dokka_version}"
    }
and make sure gradle isn't in offline mode

Comment: Yes add the dependencies but I'm getting the following error:  Error:(13, 0) Could not get unknown property 'dokka_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: @Melchior did you ever figure out the problem? The solutions below is nothing but the instructions that you (and I) already followed. There is another step missing. What is that?

Answer (score 4):

## Using Dokka with Kotlin in Android Studio for the first time

#1. Settings

##1.1 Settings in build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        version_dokka = "0.10.0"
        version_gradle = "3.5.2"
        version_kotlin = "1.3.41"
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$version_gradle"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version_kotlin"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:${version_dokka}"
        ...
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

##1.2 Settings in build.gradle(Module:app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    ...
    // Dokka used for auto-generation documentation
    dokka {
        outputFormat = 'html'
        //outputDirectory = "$buildDir/dokka"

        configuration {
            // Do not output deprecated members
            skipDeprecated = true

            // Emit warnings about not documented members.
            reportUndocumented = true

            // Do not create index pages for empty packages
            skipEmptyPackages = true
        }
    }
}

// workaround: create DocsByDokka
task DocsByDokka (type: org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask) {
    outputFormat = "html"
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/dokka"
}
```

**Don't forget to sync**

#2. Building the docs

##2.1 Your code should contain comments.
Take a look at the following link, in order to get more details:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html

##2.2 Go to the Gradle-Window in Android Studio
I have to click on "Gradle" at the right top corner in Android Studio 3
After clicking on "Gradle" a window opens.
--> MyProject --> app --> Tasks --> DocsByDokka

[image]

[Gradle-Window in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1xH3.png)

##2.3 Generate Docs
Double Click on DocsByDokka in the Gradle-Window.

#3. Find the docs
##3.1 Go to your Project-Folder
Select the Project and not the Android view. I find this by default at the left corner of Android Studio.
--> MyProject --> app --> build --> dokka --> app
There you are going to find `index.html`. Right-click and select "Open in Browser".

Answer (score 3):

So, when I ran into the issue, example I was reading, did not specify exactly where to put `dokka` dependencies. Once I figured those out, the project compiled and build:

**build.gradle (Project level file):**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    ext.dokka_version = '0.9.17'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Module level file):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
...

    dokka {
        outputFormat = 'javadoc'
        outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When running Dokka on Android code, you need to use the versions of the plugin specific to Android, instead of the stand-alone Gradle forms:

> apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'

and

> classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:${versions.dokka}"

as pointed out in the Android section of the Dokka GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

when running android `apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'`
 result is Plugin with id 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android' not found.

so change to `org.jetbrains.dokka` is working

Comment: error message say "org.jetbrains.dokka" not found so he nearly use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate Dokka documentatiton without Dokka plugin... Use [EasyDokkaPlugin](https://github.com/Vorlonsoft/EasyDokkaPlugin)

Add the following at the end of `build.gradle` of each sub-module that you wish to generate documentation:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/Vorlonsoft/EasyDokkaPlugin/master/dokka.gradle'
```

You can now generate documentation by Dokka documentation engine in Javadoc format:

```
$ gradle dokkaJavadocsJar
```